# How to integrate SwiftyJSON Cocoapod into Xcode 7.3.1 Swift 2.2

Tags: swift2, cocoapods, xcode7, swifty-json

I'm using `cocoapods` to install `SwiftyJSON` into `Xcode 7.3.1` `Swift 2.2` and I get 158 build errors. This is the `pod` I'm using:

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
```

From my understanding the branch has been updated to `Swift 3` and `Xcode 8` but I need to be on an older version, does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use swift2 branch by adding this:

:branch => 'swift2'

Comment: hey man, thanks for the advice. Do you mean like this: pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git':branch => 'swift2'

Comment: don't forget the comma between :git => 'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git', and :branch